# Seque from a storyboard image tap into a SpriteKitScene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, scene

I'm creating a Swift project for a high school programming class. I can't seem to figure out this problem, and everyone else in my class doesn't seem to have any ideas.

To start, I created a new Swift project, and chose a game format.

[image: new project template]

I then used some basic code to make the first level for my game, a maze game where the maze moves around instead of the ball based on how the user tilts the device.
This is my `GameScene.swift`:

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

var accelupdateinterval = 0.1
var accelmultiplier = 15.0

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let manager = CMMotionManager()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = accelupdateinterval
        manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
            (data, error) in

            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!) * CGFloat(accelmultiplier), CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)!) * CGFloat(accelmultiplier))

        }

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

I want to have a main menu that the app opens into, which is `mainMenu.storyboard`:

[image: menu storyboard]

I successfully have the app launching into the `mainMenu.storyboard` (and the level physics work well when I've tested the `level1.sks`), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to segue.

GOAL: I want people to be segued into the `level1.sks` (and the levels that I add later), when they tap the corresponding image in `mainMenu.storyboard`.

I can't use the method of adding a Storyboard Reference to segue it, as the Storyboard Reference won't let me choose `level1.sks`.

I'd also love to find out how to send users back to the main menu when the player icon touches the goal (the blue thing up near the top in this screenshot):

[image: game maze screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So to do this I think the best approach is to create another ViewController subclass, maybe named LauncherViewController, which will present your SKScene. Then in your storyboard add this viewController and have your menu segue to it on an image press.

Here is a start for the LauncherViewController

```
class LauncherViewController: UIViewController {

    var gameScene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        presentGameScene()
    }

    func presentGameScene(){

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        gameScene.size = skView.bounds.size
        gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(gameScene)

    }
}
```

Where in your menu controller you have a prepareForSegue like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegue" {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! LauncherViewController
        destinationViewController.gameScene = GameScene()
}
```

to have your LauncherViewController dismiss the gameScene when the user finishes the maze, use a delegate pattern. So in GameScene add a protocol above your class

```
protocol GameDelegate {
    func gameFinished()
}
```

have your LauncherViewController conform to this delegate and set the gameScene's delegate variable to self (see below)

```
class LauncherViewController: UIViewController, GameDelegate {

    var gameScene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        gameScene.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        presentGameScene()
    }

    func presentGameScene(){

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        gameScene.size = skView.bounds.size
        gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(gameScene)

    }

    func gameFinished(){
        // this forces LauncherViewController to dismiss itself
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

add a variable in GameScene to hold the delegate (LauncherViewController) and add a function that calls the delegate function. You will also need to add the logic to know when the game is over as I haven't done that.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let manager = CMMotionManager()
    var delegate: GameDelegate!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = accelupdateinterval
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
        (data, error) in

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!) * CGFloat(accelmultiplier), CGFloat((data?.acceleration.y)!) * CGFloat(accelmultiplier))

    }

}

func gameOver(){
    delegate.gameFinished()
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    // it's probably easiest to add the logic for a gameOver here
    if gameIsOver {
        gameOver()
    }
}
```

}

There will probably be some mistakes in here as I wrote this on my phone so just comment below for anything you are unsure about or doesn't work.

Comment: Great info so far @OlivierWilkinson . Thanks. I've created the LauncherViewController and added the reference to it in the main menu storyboard. However, when I control drag the 1 button to the new view controller, it won't let me choose that view controller. So I can't create the segue between the button and the Launcher View Controller. The button does have a tap gesture recognizer, too. Any thoughts?

Comment: are 1,2,3,4 and 5 UIButtons? If they are UIImages then you won't be able to connect a segue that way. instead you need to drag from the orange button on the top of your menu viewController to the launcher view controller, name the segue, and use performSegueWithIdentifier("whatever you named your segue", sender: self) in the function the gesture recogniser calls. Does that make sense? I didn't explain myself particularly well

Comment: No that made perfect sense, thank you. I changed them to buttons with an image texture, and it let me make the segue. I'll keep working for now and get back to you if I need anything else. Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: I seem to be running into an issue. I followed your solution, and It seemed to be working pretty well. However, I found (through trial and error), that the lines: 
    "gameScene.size = skView.bounds.size" AND
    "gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill"
were causing it to crash for some reason when I tapped the image, so I've commented them out for now. Now, when I tap the image, a gray box (I'm assuming this is my new scene), slides up, but nothing happens. My level1.sks doesn't show, and it's just a blank gray screen. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Hmm, I think it's not showing because the gameScene has no size, but I think view has no size in viewDidLoad which is causing the problem. Just a sec I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I changed my answer so that presentGameScene is now in viewWillAppear. If that doesn't work (with the lines uncommented out) try it in viewDidAppear. If THAT doesn't work just say and I'll fix it (it would just take a little more work). :)

Comment: After much deliberation, I decided to scrap my current plan and try to approach the game from a different direction. Thank you for all of your help, you definitely made the process more understandable. If you are interested in trying to fix this for your own personal "joy" or something, I've uploaded the whole project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5zWiD916ZwUXRBXzlVSi0xaW8/view?usp=sharing